# Why TCP segment doesn't contain IP address

Tags: tcp

Why the `TCP segment` only contains the `port numbers` but no `IP addresses`? How does the packet know which host it is going to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the TCP segment is `encapsulated` into an Internet Protocol (IP) datagram, and the IP datagram contains the `source and destination IP`.